# Improve JavaScript Speed

Tags: javascript, performance, image-loading

My website, [www.runthisday.com](http://www.runthisday.com), has JavaScript that pulls an about page to 50% of the width of the user's screen, while pushing other components to the left to make room for the about page.

The problem is that when the user clicks the about button for the first time, this JavaScript is extremely slow because Chrome waits for the images to load. For other web browser, the JavaScript is quick, but the images take a second to load. After the first use of the button, the about slide works fine. But it is the first time that really matters.

Is there a way to fix this so that the JavaScript works quickly and the images appear immediately when the button is clicked? Would directing the users to a loading page fix this? If so, can you direct me to somewhere that would show me how I can use JavaScript to load the site in that way.

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: You need to make your images smaller.  Your hammer image is a res of 5000x3333px, make it the size of your content area and set the quality in photoshop or gimp to around 50% when saving.  Right now you are pulling in large amounts of image data when the files only need to be 15-20% of their current size...just to note there is nothing wrong with the Javascript, this issue is purely asset based

Comment: You can also load a low res image first (and very quickly), possibly even off-screen before the about box is shown, and display that first, THEN load your full res image and replace the low res one when done.  I would also suggest reducing the pixel count anyway though - 5000x3333 is very large.  The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/467943/4098951) might help you.

Comment: Also consider right now a 5000x3333 image is extremely bandwidth intensive for mobile users, the page load could end up costing them a few MB of data, and will load extremely slow often meaning they won't stick around to load your site

Comment: Hey, thanks you guys! This really helped.

Comment: @c_harrris you're most welcome, good luck! :)

Answer (score 4):

Your images are *huge*. So start by resizing those to a much more manageable size.

But another thing you can do is preload your images. Here's a simple wrapper that you can use to load some images and know when they're ready.

```js
// Url -> Promise<ImageElement>
var image = function(src) {
  return new Promise(function(pass, fail) {
    var i = new Image()
    i.src = src
    i.onload = event=> pass(i)
  })
}
    
var url = "http://www.runthisday.com/img/the_hammer.jpg"
image(url).then(elem => document.body.appendChild(elem))
```

You could even use a `Promise.all` wrapper to ensure multiple images have loaded for a particular section

```
Promise.all([
  image('one.jpg'),
  image('two.jpg'),
  image('three.jpg')
]).then(images => console.log("all images loaded", images)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the images are always the same, probably you can store in web cache... for ever... In order to just wait the first time...

Other option is not to load big images, probably you can use some repetitive titled images... in some places and really when needed load images...